# What is the meaning of 说得过?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

两千七百多年前的战国末期，赵国名将赵奢有个儿子叫赵括，他从小读了不少兵书，跟别人谈论起军事来，没有人说得过他，就是父亲赵奢也难不住他。赵括因此很骄傲，自以为天下无敌，连父亲也不放在眼里。

Hi all. I found this in the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 15. What is the meaning of 说得过？Here the 说 is pronounced shui4 or shuo1?

提前感谢。

Comment: win the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pronounced as shuo1.

过 in 说得过 means 胜过(surpass, be better than). 说得过 overall means something along the lines of ***better in terms of speaking/arguing***.

It forms a sort of pattern "verb+得/不+过". E.g. 跑不过，玩不过，打得过， etc.

Answer (score 4):

跟别人谈论起军事来，
(in) discussing military matters,
没有人说得过他，
nobody could out talk him,
none was more erudite than he,
he had no equal,
he was peerless,
none was more knowledgeable than he,